# Connecting to GPS

Tags: gps

I am running QGIS on a Panasonic CF-20 toughbook. When I run GPS viewer I get satelite connection and it connects via COM 6 at a baud rate of 9600. Within QGIS when in the GPS panel I select serial device "COM6: Sierra Wireless NMEA Port". I get a connection with yellow strength but in the details it says "8 satellites used (0 in view)". When I select the satellite viewer no satelite histograms are visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using an external antenna?

Comment: no built in I assume